# Pagination with php and ajax from file

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I want to use pagination in php with the use ajax and data are coming from file. while searching a key word the page shows 1st 20 records from a file but now i want next remaining record from file and it should use pagination. Any suggestion please?

```
$keyword=$_POST['data'];
$file = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/searchengine/searchDeals?searchKeyword=".$keyword."");
$output = "[";
$line = 1;
if ( !($fp = fopen($file, "r") ) )
exit("Unable to open the input file.");
while( !feof($fp) && $line <= 20 ) 
{
if($line != 20){
 $output = $output.fgets($fp).","; 
  }else{    
 $output = $output.fgets($fp); 
}
 $line++;
}
fclose($fp);
$output = $output."]";
echo $output;
```

Comment: Please feel free to include some code that you have tried.

Comment: i was using manually now i want to do it with ajax. i am posting my manual code

Comment: I have done this its send top 20 records from file. to ajax and there it desplays the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to count the total number of pages. It's `floor(number_of_lines_in_file / 20)`.

To switch to different pages you'll have to pass the selected page variable(through $_GET for example) and get lines from `$page_number - 1 * 20` to `$page_number * 20`. You can either get the lines from the loop or think of something more advanced like using `fseek` maybe...

**But** the easiest approach would probably be using PHP's `file()` function instead, which will save the file into an array, and you'll only have to get required portion of lines using `array_slice`.