# How to call a jQuery function as fast as possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I am using a PHP only pagination method shown here:
[How to create AJAX pagination without a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265095/how-to-create-ajax-pagination-without-a-database/31265537?noredirect=1#answer-31265537)
And I have the following code for my menu:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my-btn").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#div").offset().top
        }, 2000, "swing", function(){
            $("#shiny").effect('shake', {times: 1, direction: 'left', distance: 5}, 300);
        });
    });
});
```

Since only a portion of the page changes I have devided the menu links to bring the user into different parts of the page. For example if the first page contains element `#div` the user clicks on the global template element `#my-btn` (from the menu) and the screen scrolls and the text shakes once. But what if the button actually links to another page? I want that same effect to execute even when on another page that contains different element, for example `#second-div`.

So I wonder if there is a way to execute this function once the user clicks on a menu item and moves from `index.php?limit=1&amp;page=0` to `index.php?limit=1&amp;page=1` or vise-versa.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this: you could use a class and specify the elements using that.

`... scrollTop: $('.myClass').offset().top ...`

Or you could pass in the `id` as part of the function when you click (meaning you'd have to specify for every page:

```
<a id="my-btn" href="javascript:void();" data-div="#second-div">Scroll Button</a>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#my-btn").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var divToAnimate = $(this).data('div');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(divToAnimate).offset().top
        }, 2000, "swing", function(){
            $("#shiny").effect('shake', {times: 1, direction: 'left', distance:                  5}, 300);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Still it doesn't animate but just jumps to the element with the id.